# Mouse Event draw rectangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv3.0

I can't work out why this doesn't work to draw a blue square on a black background where I click on the image. I can see that `x` and `y` are being recognized, and when I take the `cv2.rectangle` line out of the function it works.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def print_xy(event,x,y,flags,params):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        x2=x+100
        y2=y+100
        print(x,y)
        print(x2,y2)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),3)

#draw a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)

cv2.imshow('image', img)

cv2.setMouseCallback('image',print_xy)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I don't know `opencv` at all, but I'd guess you have to explicitly tell it to draw the updated image. Perhaps call `imshow` again from within `print_xy`?

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks very much